# Is the following stopping time finite: $T:=\inf\{t\geq 0:B_t\geq \sqrt{t}+1\}?$

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

We have a Brownian motion process $B$ and a stopping time defined like this:
$$T:=\inf\{t\geq 0:B_t\geq \sqrt{t}+1\}.$$

Is this stopping time almost surely finite, eg. $T<\infty$, and why?

My intuition would say it is.

Comment: What is your intuition?

Comment: That we know the $\limsup_{t\to \infty}\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}=\infty$ a.s. And that means that the BM has to go over $\sqrt{t}$ at some point.

Comment: If you know that, then isn't that a proof?  How do you know that limsup is $\infty$?